# как сделать каждому игроку отдельную камеру

Tags: unity3d

здравия желаю, я делаю многопользовательскую игру на unity2D при помощи Mirror. Столкнулся с проблемой: нужно сделать каждому игроку свою камеру, но при использовании этого кода и громадное количество других, камера просто следует за игроком, который подключился недавно:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Mirror;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerCamera : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam; // камера тут

    void Start()
    {
        // если я игрок, останови
        if (isLocalPlayer) 
            return;

        // отключение камеры другого игрока
        cam.enabled = false;
    }

}
```

**ищу ответ уже 2 дня, помогите**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

напиши мне ВКонтакте, - https://vk.com/id622371636
Я тебе дам более подробный ответ.
Здесь могу кратко сказать: на стороне клиента всегда должен быть только один объект с камерой - главный персонаж конкретного игрока. То есть, тот объект, которым управляет игрок.
Простой пример:
К игре подключено 2 игрока:
Вася и Петя
У Васи главным персонажем с камерой будет Вася
У Пети главным персонажем с камерой будет Петя

Как это реализовать? Очень просто.
Представим, сейчас у тебя на сервере вообще нет игроков
Подключается Петя
Сервер отправляет Пете данные "connect" при котором создаётся главный персонаж с камерой
А всем остальным игрокам отправляется команда "new_player" при которой просто создаётся объект Пети без камеры

Если непонятно - напиши мне в ВК, я тебе отвечу на все вопросы, потому что сам сталкивался с этими проблемами, когда только начинал работать с сетевыми проектами

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой скрипт камеры, может поможет

```
 public GameObject Car;
 public GameObject Camera_obj;
 public Transform CameraRotator;
  
 private void Update()
 {
     if (isLocalPlayer)
     {
         CameraRotator.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Car.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity);
        
     }
     if (!isLocalPlayer) 
     { 
         Destroy(Camera_obj);
     }
     
    
 }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]